# Sobrescrita de arquivo txt em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Minha dúvida é bem básica:

Como faço para, sempre que for gravar algo em um arquivo (txt), sempre começar a gravar depois das informações que já estavam ali escritas?

Quer dizer, como faço para não sobrescrever o conteúdo de um arquivo que já tinha informações inscritas?

**Linguagem C, no caso**

Answer (score 7):

Basta você abrir o arquivo com [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) no modo *append*:

```
FILE *file = fopen("meuarquivo.txt", "a");
```

Comment: @LuigiWagner considere marcar a resposta como aceita.